# program to extract JPEGs from raw data file creates segmentation fault (in C)

Tags: c, io, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm new to writing programs that read or write files and I am totally stuck as to the reason I keep getting a segmentation fault. I feel like it might have to do with one of my file pointers or newly created files, but any help by more experienced eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Another piece of information - while I was trying to debug the program, it seemed to be stuck checking the if statements around line 35 for longer than I would expect, then eventually - segmentation fault.

Here is my complete code below:

```
    // program to recover deleted JPEGs from memory card

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: recover inputFile\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // remember filename
    char *infile = argv[1];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

// read raw input file
    int buffer[512];
    int counter = 0;
    char filename[8];
    FILE* img;

    // repeat until EOF
    while (fread (&buffer, 1, 512, inptr) == 512)
    {
        //fread (&buffer, 1, 512, inptr);  // this might be redundant (while statement)
    // check for start of JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
            buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
            buffer[2] == 0xff &&
            (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (counter > 0) // if this is not the first jpeg found, we need to close previous jpeg
            {
                fclose(img);
            }
            // create and open file
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            counter ++; //keep track of current jpeg count

            img = fopen(filename, "w");
            // make sure our pointer wasn't NULL
            if (img == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", filename);
                return 2;
            }
            do
            {
            // Write current buffer to JPEG
            fwrite (&buffer, 512, 1, img);
            fread (&buffer, 1, 512, inptr);
            }
            // making sure to stop at start of new JPEG
            while ((buffer[0] == 0xff &&
                    buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
                    buffer[2] == 0xff &&
                    (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) == 0);
            // move cursor back one 512 byte block so it can be re-read for if-statement
            fseek (inptr, -512, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    // close remaining open files
    fclose(img);
    fclose(inptr);
}
```

Comment: `fread (&buffer,` -> `fread (buffer,`

Comment: Also you wouldn't read `int`s but characters, and *these should be `unsigned`*. This same task has been asked a lot so you can google around

Comment: In any case, it is *your* task to *localize the segmentation fault* by using a debugger.

Comment: Also, you should `fseek` back a count of bytes you have actually read using previous `fread` call, not 512.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, it doesn't matter, in both cases `fread` will get `void*` pointer to the same memory address

Comment: Thanks guys, the type was one of the big problems as you said.

Comment: @Andrii I'm trying to figure out how to fseek back by the count of bytes from my previous fread call without calling fread again - do I need to store it in a variable?

Comment: @aherzfeld, `fread` returns "The total number of elements successfully read"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segmentation fault ended up being at the end of the program when it tried to close the img file which was never opened. Using int instead of unsigned char was causing a failure in the if-statement comparisons.